# IEEE C37.118 python parser of PMU RAW file

Tags: python, parsing

Here is sample output data that comes from a Phasor Measurement Unit (PMU) device placed in the distribution network. PMU device is based on IEEE C37.118 standard. Here are sample 3 records:

```
+---------+---------------+----------+

15:28:59,420,551   ETHER

|0   |f4|03|43|3e|e0|18|00|45|1d|62|5f|f9|08|00|45|00|00|4e|a7|88|00|00|3c|06|35|d3|c0|a8|84|85|0a|14|52|0d|12|68|ee|2c|08|1d|21|f6|27|9a|9b|fa|50|18|20|00|7e|06|00|00|aa|01|00|26|00|06|60|21|58|bb|ff|06|68|20|08|04|f2|48|d7|b1|00|00|00|00|fe|3c|fb|47|fe|37|fb|46|00|04|ff|ff|f2|db|



+---------+---------------+----------+

15:28:59,440,855   ETHER

|0   |f4|03|43|3e|e0|18|00|45|1d|62|5f|f9|08|00|45|00|00|4e|a7|8c|00|00|3c|06|35|cf|c0|a8|84|85|0a|14|52|0d|12|68|ee|2c|08|1d|22|1c|27|9a|9b|fa|50|18|20|00|a5|d5|00|00|aa|01|00|26|00|06|60|21|58|bb|ff|06|b6|00|08|04|f2|4d|d7|b0|00|00|00|00|fe|3c|fb|47|fe|37|fb|46|00|04|ff|ff|7d|02|



+---------+---------------+----------+
```

Does anyone has idea where can I find Python implementation, PIP package or anything similar for parser that could convert this data in some sensible dataframe?
Any info could be useful.

Comment: What would be a desired result?

Comment: @baduker DataFrame with header titles that corresponding to bits of data. Titles would be something like angles, voltage, power, etc. Basically someone who is into  C37.118 standard and PMU parsing in general should have idea about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created script that parses these types of files and outputs them in Excel:

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
from tzlocal import get_localzone

tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
listofrecords = []
i=0
finalDict = {}
with open("inputData/PMU-Location1.txt",'r') as pmuraw:    
    for line in pmuraw.readlines(): #read in multiple lines
        if len(line.strip())==0:
            continue
        if line.startswith('+---------+---------------+----------+'):
            record = {}           
        if "ETHER" in line:
            record["Time"],record["Network"] = line.strip().rstrip().split(sep="   ")
        if "|" in line:
            for i, value in enumerate(line.strip().rstrip().split(sep="|")):
                record[i] = value
            record["SYNC"] = int((str(record[56])+" "+str(record[57])).strip().rstrip().replace(" ",""),16)
            record["Packet size"] = int((str(record[58])+" "+str(record[59])).strip().rstrip().replace(" ",""),16)
            record["PMU ID"] =  int((str(record[60])+" "+str(record[61])).strip().rstrip().replace(" ",""),16)
            record["Timestamp"] = datetime.fromtimestamp(int((str(record[62])+" "+str(record[63])+" "+str(record[64])+" "+str(record[65])).strip().rstrip().replace(" ",""), 16)).astimezone(tz).strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
            record["Time diff"] = str(timedelta(microseconds = int((str(record[67])+" "+str(record[68])+""+str(record[69])).strip().rstrip().replace(" ",""),16)))[6:]
            record["Status PMU"] =  int((str(record[70])+" "+str(record[71])).strip().rstrip().replace(" ",""),16)
            
            record["Fazor 1"] = int((str(record[72])+" "+str(record[73])+" "+ str(record[74])+" "+str(record[75])).strip().rstrip().replace(" ",""),16)
            record["Fazor 2"] =  int((str(record[76])+" "+str(record[77])+" "+ str(record[78])+" "+str(record[79])).strip().rstrip().replace(" ",""),16)
            record["Fazor 3"] =  int((str(record[80])+" "+str(record[81])+" "+ str(record[82])+" "+str(record[83])).strip().rstrip().replace(" ",""),16)
            record["Fazor 4"] =  int((str(record[84])+" "+str(record[85])+" "+ str(record[86])+" "+str(record[87])).strip().rstrip().replace(" ",""),16)
            record["Frequency"] =  int((str(record[88])+" "+str(record[89])).strip().rstrip().replace(" ",""),16)
            record["Delta freq"] =  int((str(record[90])+" "+str(record[91])).strip().rstrip().replace(" ",""),16)        
            remove = [k for k in record if isinstance(k, (int, np.integer))]
            for k in remove: del record[k]            
            listofrecords.append(record)           


PMU-Location1DF = pd.DataFrame(listofrecords)
PMU-Location1DF.to_excel("outputData/PMU-Location1.xlsx",sheet_name='PMU Žerjavinec', encoding='UTF-8')
```